# Как правильно парсить страницу на python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Есть вот такая страница:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
      let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
          "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
      ));
      return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
  };

var theme = getCookie("theme");
document.getElementById("cookie").innerHTML = theme;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="cookie"></p>
    <script src="/assets/js/cookies.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Это просто страница для обучения парсингу данных с html. Всё парсится просто замечательно, но есть одно НО! Тут должны быть в `value` cookie, которые передаются странице из js, но я их не наблюдаю.

Как мне получить страницу с уже введёнными cookie?

Парсинг страницы провожу через `requests` вот таким образом: `res = requests.get("http://localhost/cookie.py")`

При парсинге я получаю только вот это:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="cookie"></p>
    <script src="/assets/js/cookies.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Хотя в `<p id="cookie"></p>` должны быть данные. Что с этим делать?

PS Понял что `requests` не подходит для этого, т.к. не ждёт конца загрузки страницы. Как дождаться конца загрузки страницы и спарсить уже с данными?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `requests` есть класс `Session`, который по идее отвечает за хранение cookie и авторизационной информации.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get(..)
session.post(...)
```

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но куки я просто взял чтобы можно было хоть какую-то информацию взять. А на деле мне надо вытащить то значение, которое js передаёт в параграф html файла, но я не знаю как правильно спрасить его...

Comment: Куки посмотреть после запроса можно в сессии. А вот вытащить текст, который js прописывает через requests не получится. Надо парсить с помощью Selenium - то есть фактически через браузер - вот, например, статейка об этом: https://proglib.io/p/web-scraping